# Laravel livewire not handle listener from broadcast

Tags: laravel, broadcast, laravel-livewire, laravel-echo

I tried to listen event emited from broadcast in laravel livewire but nothing happen;

on my bootstrap.js i have:

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'myKey',
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    disableStat: true,
    forceTLS: false,
});
```

my event laravel

```
class TaskFinished implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function broadcastAs(){
        return 'task-finish';
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('TaskTricolor');
    }
}
```

my listener

```
class SendTaskNotif
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  TaskFinished  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(TaskFinished $event)
    {
    }
}
```

and my livewire component

```
protected $listeners = ['echo:TaskTricolor,TaskFinished' => 'eventlisten'];

    // public function getListeners(){
    //     return [
    //         'echo:TaskTricolor,TaskFinished' => 'eventlisten'
    //     ];
    // }

    public function start(){
        $this->start = true;
        $tricolors = new TricolorController();
        $this->tricolor = $tricolors->start();
    }

    public function stop(){
        $this->start = false;
        $tricolors = new TricolorController();
        $this->tricolor = $tricolors->stop();
    }
    

    public function emet(){
        event(new TaskFinished());
    }

    public function eventlisten(){
        $vars = "test";
        dd($vars);
    }
```

on my listener i put `dd('test')` and when the emet function is called, the dd value is showed;

So when i test with livewire listener handler, nothing happen, my dd not appear, and no error;

I tried to console log Echo from blade to test if i can handle listener, but it show that Echo is not defined, but when i console.log window, i see Echo inside
[image: console.log(window) result]

On my websocket dashboard i have this:
[image: websocket dashboard Events]

I don't know if it can help to solve, i use beyondcode/laravel-websockets package as driver

Answer (score 1):

When I first started to use Livewire (version 1.0) we listened the messages using vanilla javascript and then called the Livewire.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    window.Echo.private('TaskTricolor')
        .listen('.task-finish', (response) => { 
            window.Livewire.emit('task-finish', response));
        }
    });
```

You can try this. It's not a clean solution as your approach, but I think is easier to debug.

Comment: tried this and i console.log('text') inside the listen but nothing appear

Comment: Did you tried change the Echo.private to Echo.channel?

Comment: yeah, i changed, on start project, my websocket see that the event TaskTricolor is there, and when calling event(new TaskFinished()), there is no notification on the websocket dashboard, i don't know if it must show the event called or not, but no reaction from the Echo; More information, i used laravel-websocket driver, not pusher, if it can help to solve

Comment: Didn't know. So this problem doesn't look that is related to the livewire or javascript. Echo can't hear anything. Your app.blade.php have the tag `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue; on my event class i should use ShouldBroadCastNow instead ShouldBroadCast

```
class TaskFinished implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function broadcastAs(){
        return 'task-finish';
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('TaskTricolor');
    }
}
```

the ShouldBroadCast put the event in queue, so it's not activated on event called, but ShouldBroadCastNow listen the event immediately, [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-echo-not-listening-on-events) link i found the explanation

Answer (score 0):

add metadata in your template

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

declare token in your boostrap.js

```
let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');
    window.Echo = new Echo({
         broadcaster: 'push',
    .....
    ...
    auth: {
             headers: {
                 Authorization: 'Bearer' + token,
             },
         },
```

and call event with

```
document. addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
     window.Echo.private('TaskTricolor')
         .listen('.task-finish', (response) => {
             window.Livewire.emit('task-finish'));
         }
     });
```